# Low Yearly Archives: Exclude current year

Tags: low-yearly-archives

Firstly thanks for this handy plugin.

I am trying to exclude the current year from my archive list.

So in 2014, my tag looks like:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" end_year="2013" }
```

Yet 2014 is listed...as is 2013 which is empty.

I've tried a few variations but no luck. Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Is it possible to exclude the current year?

Thanks again for all your EE extensions.

CJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to go about this:

**1. Use a conditional**

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news"}
    {if year != '{current_time format="%Y"}'}
        ...
    {/if}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

**2. Use PHP on Input**

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" end_year="<?=(date('Y')-1)?>" end_month="12"}
    ...
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```